# How to make Connected Modal windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am wondering how to replicated the same modal window components used on Lonely Planet: http://www.lonelyplanet.com/interest/family-travel/best-of-family-travel/content/travel-tips-and-articles/2550

So when you click on one of the listed thumbnails you will see the modal window with the arrows which on hover state displays the preview image. I am trying to recreate the same plugin with Zurb Foundation or plain JS, jquery which at the end will be implemented into Wordpress. I know this is not the platform to ask this kind of questions but yeah. I don't know where to start.

If you have any suggestions of plugins or whatsoever please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which thumbnails are you talking about ?? unable to find thumbnails on the given link...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own plugin using Zurb Foundation, you can get an idea from the following code.
http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/GZaOGV

```
$(function(){

  $("#exampleModal2").foundation('open');
  $('.nav').click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('prev')){
        if($(".reveal-overlay:visible").prev().find('.reveal').length){
            $(".reveal-overlay:visible").prev().find('.reveal').foundation('open');   
        } else{
            $(".reveal-overlay:last").find('.reveal').foundation('open'); 
        }  
      }else{
        if($(".reveal-overlay:visible").next().find('.reveal').length){
            $(".reveal-overlay:visible").next().find('.reveal').foundation('open');    
        }else{
            $(".reveal-overlay:first").find('.reveal').foundation('open'); 
        }   
      }          
  });

});
```

If you want to use plugin you can use slick slider and customize it to your needs.
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/